# Prove $\frac{|a|-|b|}{1-|ab|}\leq \frac{|a+b|}{|1+ab|}\leq \frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|ab|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Prove $\frac{|a|-|b|}{1-|ab|}\leq \frac{|a+b|}{|1+ab|}\leq \frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|ab|}$ where $|a|,|b|<1$.

My idea: Take $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ holomorphic with $f(-a)=0$ and the conformal map $h:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ with
$$h(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-az}.$$
Then the inverse of $h$ is
$$h^{-1}(z)=\frac{a+z}{1+az}.$$
Then the holomorphic mapping
$$g(z)=f\circ h(z)$$
satisfies $g(0)=0$. Then by Scharwz lemma
$$|f\circ h(z)|\leq |z|.$$
Which implies
$$|f(z)|\leq \left| \frac{a+z}{1+az}\right|.$$
If I am able to prove that I can choose $f(b)=\frac{|a|-|b|}{1-|ab|}$ then I get the first Inequality and I can get the other in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is not true. Take $a:=i/2, b=i/2$ to see a counter example.
The right inequality should be
$$\frac{|a|-|b|}{1+|ab|}\leq \frac{|a+b|}{|1+ab|}\leq \frac{|a|+|b|}{1-|ab|}$$
Its demonstration is straightforward.

Comment: I don't get your counterexample. Why you take $a=i|a|$ and $b=i|b|$, I mean you could have just taken them $a=a$ and $b=b$. Because the modulus is the same. But anyways, I don't see how you assure the inequality is false. @ParesseuxNguyen

Comment: @user226755  So you take $a=b=i/2$, what your ineq implies is $$0 \le 4/3 \le 4/5$$

Comment: Thank you! I found this exercise in the book of Conway of functions of one complex variable. I didn't imagine it was false.  Actually, now that I look closely, it has a typo in the second inequality, maybe he tried to write a different inequality. @ParesseuxNguyen

Comment: @user226755 year, surely. Even the first one is wrong, you can take $a=i/2 ,b= -i/3$, the first ineq gives you $$1/5 \le 1/7$$